# OpenCv and TensorFlow AttributeError: module 'cv2.dnn' has no attribute 'readNetFromTensorFlow'

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow

When I execute this line of code

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorFlow(args["model"])
```

python3.6 x86 says AttributeError: module 'cv2.dnn' has no attribute 'readNetFromTensorFlow'

Comment: What version of opencv are you using?

Comment: I use version 3.4.1

Comment: The `dnn` module is available in all versions from 3.3. Your OpenCV was somehow not compiled with the `dnn` module. I suggest you to install OpenCV again and make sure `dnn` is listed inside

Comment: ok but with cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe everything works fine.I use virtualenv and pip to install opencv.How install opencv with dnn module?

Comment: Do you have tensorflow installed?

Comment: I have installed tensorflow but still can not work

Comment: Sorry I have no ideas from here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also encountered the same problem, and I found it is caused by a typo. It should be

`net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(args["model"])`

the "f" of Tensorflow should be lower case.

Check out the document
https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html#gad820b280978d06773234ba6841e77e8d